# Using definition of sequence convergence to prove a limit

Tags: real-analysis

Using the definition of sequence convergence, prove that if $\lim{y_n}=2$, then $\lim{3(y_n)^2-2} = 10$.

Note: not allowed to use the Algebraic Limit Theorem, ONLY allowed to use the definition of sequence convergence.

I understand how to prove a sequence converges using the definition and epsilon argument, I'm just not sure how to use the idea to connect the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $(3y_n^2-2)-10=3y_n^2-12=3(y_n^2-4)=3(y_n+2)(y_n-2)$.

**Hint 2:** You need the following fact.

Claim: Suppose $a_n \to L$. Then $a_n$ is bounded.

Proof: By definition, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, we have $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$. Pick any $\epsilon$ (say $\epsilon=1$). Then there exists $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, we have $-1<a_n-L<1$. Therefore, $L-1<a_n<L+1$. Clearly, $|a_n|<\max\{|L+1|,|L-1|\}$ for $n\geq N$. Then $|a_n|\leq \max_{1\leq j < N} |a_j|$. Therefore, $a_n$ is bounded.

Comment: When you put absolute values around everything, you want to bound the non $|y_n-2|$ terms.

Comment: So I have the terms 3, $y_n -2$, and $y_n+2$ all in absolute values.  Obviously 3 is bounded by 3, $y_n-2$ is bounded by my epsilon value that I choose, but I'm just not sure how to justify that $y_n +2$ is bounded.

Comment: See the hint I added.